# Having trouble initialising unsigned int *Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, break, unsigned-integer

in Header

```
class foo
{
    unsigned int *Indices;
    unsigned int *func(int var);
};

in CPP    
unsigned int *foo::func(int var)
{
    Indices = new unsigned int[((unsigned)var *3)];
    //do math.
    return Indices;
}
```

on initialisation of the array of Indices I get a break inside `malloc.c`
what is going on here? why am I getting the break?

I have a feeling it is because `int var` is not known at compile time. is this correct?
I have tried also using magic numbers instead of var but the problem persists

Comment: all you have to do is specify an integer in the `[]` e.g. `new int[3]`

Comment: Your code looks ok. Try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To recreate the problem you shouldn't need any more information.

the area of code i get the break on in malloc.c is..
Line 57

__forceinline void * __cdecl _heap_alloc (size_t size)

{

    if (_crtheap == 0) {
        _FF_MSGBANNER();    /* write run-time error banner */

        _NMSG_WRITE(_RT_CRT_NOTINIT);  /* write message */
        __crtExitProcess(255);  /* normally _exit(255) */
    }

    return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1);   <-----BREAKS HERE
}

Comment: You probably have already caused heap corruption elsewhere in the program

Comment: Note there's no `int*` array in your code.

Comment: Either `var` is very large or negative, or you've corrupted the heap or leaked a load of memory (both of which are very easy to do if you're juggling raw pointers like this). Try checking the value of `var` before allocation, and use `std::vector<unsigned int>` instead of hoping the user does the right thing with the loaded gun you currently return.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are right,

> it is because int var

But problem rather in value but not in type. Try to check var before allocation memory. E.g.:

```cpp
unsigned int *foo::func(int var)
{
    if (var <= 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Indices = new unsigned int[var *3];
    //do math.
    return Indices;
}
```

Comment: var is a constant of 4.